# GORM (grails) - cache blob image or something else

Tags: caching, grails, blob, grails-orm

Let's say I have a domain class

```
class Profile{
    String name
    byte[] logo
}
```

and a controller:

```
class ImageController {
    def renderImage ={
       def image = Profile.get(params.id).logo
       if (image) {
            response.setContentLength(image.length)
            response.getOutputStream().write(image)
        } else {
             response.sendError(404)
        }    
    }
}
```

and a gsp:

```
 <img width="48" 
      height="48"
      src="${createLink(controller: 'image', action: 'renderImage', id: 1)}">
```

Ok so so far so good. The image renders fine and I am happy. However, since the gsp snippet is part of my main layout the image is rendered each time I reload a page.

My question: is there a way to cache this image (blob mysql)? I have 2nd level caching turned on etc. But I am not sure if the image is cached or not. How would you do this?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `static mapping = { cache true }` to your Profile domain class to turn on caching.  As long as you fetch the Profile objects with `get(id)`, it'll use the cached version.  If you're using a more complicated query, you'll need to let grails know the query is cacheable too.

See the [Caching section](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#caching) in the Grails manual. Also, it can be helpful to turn on [hibernate SQL logging](http://grails.org/FAQ#Q%3a%20How%20can%20I%20turn%20on%20logging%20for%20hibernate%20in%20order%20to%20see%20SQL%20statements,%20input%20parameters%20and%20output%20results?) to confirm the objects are cached.